# Problems trying to use cProfile

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to run the code below at Python 2.7 GUI:

```
python -m cProfile -s time abc.py
```

However here is the error I have:

```
>>> python -m cProfile -s time abc.py     
>>>                  ^
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: You need to run this from the command line, not a GUI.

Comment: Side-note: DO NOT NAME YOUR MODULE `abc`! There is already a [built-in `abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that is used to support abstract base classes (which are used in many parts of Python under the covers). If you name your module `abc.py` and run Python in the same directory as that file, it will shadow the built-in module, and you will get mysterious errors when it turns out Python (or some import you perform) actually depends on the original `abc` module. You might get away with it for a while, until you accidentally take a dependency on `abc` and everything dies.

Comment: thanks for the note ShadowRanger! abc was just a random name I used for this question, would defo take that note in the future though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this from the command line, **not** a GUI or the interactive Python prompt. Seeing the `>>>` means you are on the interactive Python prompt.

**On the command line** a.k.a terminal window, change to the directory in which `abc.py` is located and enter:

```
python -m cProfile -s time abc.py
```

I get this:

```
python -m cProfile -s time abc.py 
         2 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:1(<module>)
```

The option `-m` does this:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

The Python version is 2.7.12.

### EDIT

If you want to do it from the interactive prompt, probably the easiest way is to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) or [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/). Then you can do this:

```
[1] %run -m cProfile -s time abc.py
```

Comment: I have already changed the directory to where abc.py is located. Plus if it is because of the directory address, it wouldn't say "cProfile" is causing the syntax error, rather it would say "can't find file" instead I suppose?

Comment: You are in the interactive Python interpreter when you see `>>>`. You need to be on command line of your OS for this command to work.

Comment: Yes, in prompt it does work, but i was thinking whether I can do that in interpreter, because interpreter is more flexible for me to copy and paste the result and analyse.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m ...`  is not itself Python syntax: it's a syntax for starting Python from outside.   Therefore, the Python interpreter (GUI or not) will fail to process that command.  (We know you're working from inside the Python interpreter because of the telltale `>>>` prompt.)

What does "from outside" mean?  It means you need to type that command at the `>` prompt in the Command Window (in Windows) or at the `$` prompt in a terminal window running the bash shell (in other likely OSes).